# jCarousel scrolling from right to left

Tags: jquery, css, jcarousel, horizontal-scrolling, right-to-left

i am trying to reverse the scrolling direction of Jcarousel and make it scroll from right to left. anyone knows how that is done?

I attach here a link to the Jcarousel code file, perhaps this can help.
http://174.133.190.8/~goldarch/jquery.jcarousel.min.js

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution + demo = http://tech.c-dan.com/cweaks.aspx (vertical in my case, config option changes it to horizontal)

Comment: brilliant! i will give this a try!

Comment: The links is not active anymore. Could you please tell us how it works?